# Connecting over HTTP to VirtualBox on Win10

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, puphpet

I've set up a VirtualBox using Vagrant and [Puphpet](https://puphpet.com/). The box has set up ok and I can login with Putty to `127.0.0.1` to port `2222`.

My problem is that I can't seem to connect over any other routes, namely HTTP.

Hitting 192.168.56.101 in a browser results in "took too long to respond". The networking to the box is set to NAT, with Adapter2 set to Host Only.

[Here's my puphpet YAML config file](https://gist.github.com/meigwilym/4e7851e8d02ea3b0881e5e707b0711af).

Comment: first make sure the site is running correctly from the VM - ssh into VM and check with `curl http://192.168.56.101` that the site is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a forwarding rule in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
```

Or you define the forwarding rule in Virtualbox

Restart t he Box after definition of forwarding rule.

Comment: you dont need to define forwarded port when you assign a static IP - Its only usefull if you dont have the static IP